# Logcat flooded by Minwook devBounds

Tags: android, logcat, skia, android-13

today i updated my Samsung A53 to Android 13 and after this when i debug my app the logcat gets flooded by the following message

```
 2023-05-11 16:00:08.936  3766-3892  skia package.name D  Minwook devBounds(70.2) Offset.fX(-6.4)
```

Does anyone know where this message comes from and how i can get rid of it? The message arrives every 10 ms (more or less) and makes me unable to read any of my logs. I don't know if this helps but there is a BottomSheet opened when this message start to fill the logs. The Problem never occured on Android 12 (the previous version on the phone) and i don't know of any other version with the same problem.

Thanks for help!